# Why Spring Controller doesn't deserialize to a List field?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a `Book` entity that has a list of attributes `Price`, called `prices`. My `Price` entity has a `BigDecimal value` and a `PriceType type`. `PriceType` is an Enum with `EBOOK,PRINTED,COMBO`. My form is this:

```
<form action="/Sprong/products" method="post">
        <div>
            <label>Title</label> 
            <input type="text" name="title" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Description</label>
            <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Pages</label> 
            <input type="number" name="pages" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <c:forEach items="${types}" var="priceType" varStatus="status">
                <div>
                    <label>${priceType}</label> 
                    <input type="number" name="prices[${status.index}].value" /> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="prices[${status.index}].type" value="${priceType}" />
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit book</button>
    </form>
```

And the controller which handle this form is this:

```
  @Controller
  public class BookController {

  @Autowired
  private DAOBook daoBook;

  @RequestMapping("/products/form")
  public ModelAndView form() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("products/form");
    modelAndView.addObject("types", PriceType.values());
    return modelAndView;
  }

  @RequestMapping("/products")
  public String save(Book book) {
    daoBook.insert(book);
    System.out.println(book);
    return "products/success";
  }

}
```

This first method returns the form and when it is filled, data is saved with second method. Using Chrome's F12, I had this Network screeshot:

[image]

But when I debugging in Eclipse I got this:

[image]

Here is `Price` entity:

```
 @Embeddable
 public class Price {

 BigDecimal value;
 PriceType type;

 @Deprecated
 public void setValue(BigDecimal value) {
    this.value = value;
 }

 @Deprecated
 public void setType(PriceType type) {
    this.type = type;
 }
}
```

I'm using `@Deprecated` to setters since I could [use them wrongly](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073723/core-java/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html). Is it possible this annotation is messing with `spring-mvc`?

**EDIT**

Here's my `Book` class:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String title;
private String description;
private int pages;

@ElementCollection
private List<Price> prices;

@Deprecated
public void setPrices(List<Price> prices) {
    this.prices = prices;
}

@Deprecated
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@Deprecated
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Deprecated
public void setPages(int pages) {
    this.pages = pages;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Book [title=" + title + ", description=" + description + ", pages=" + pages + "]";
}

}
```

Comment: What you really need to show is the Book class. The missing mapping for price occurs for this class.

Comment: I just added `Book` class

Comment: Your Book class doesn't have a getter for the prices.

Comment: @JB Nizet  To deserialize , you don't need getter I think

Comment: @JBNizet I added a getter and it worked. Although it worked, I didn't find any documentation about/how/when spring-mvc uses getters/setters, I mean, when they are really necessary. Do you guys have any? And JBNizet, could please formulate an answer for acceptance?

Comment: @GabrielRado You don't have getters for other fields (id, title...) and yet these are correctly valued during deserialization. A clearer explanation would be interesting I think.

Comment: AFAIK, when Spring binds parameters such as prices[0].value, it starts by calling getPrices(). If that returns a list (because you might want a specific type of list, or a prepopulated list), if gets the first element of the list (again, you might already have objects there, that must be mutated). If the object isn't there, it's created and added. If the list isn't there, it's created and set.

Comment: The behavior described by you seems to fit what I experienced. Do you have any manual/documentation about it?

Comment: Indeed. Spring handles differently deserialization with application/x-www-form-urlencoded and application/json content type. The OP uses very probably the first one. For this content type, the collection field from the java side has to indeed provide a getter. I think that an answer would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshots, the request sent to the server doesn't use the `application/json` content type but very probably the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type.
By using this content type, Spring doesn't rely on the Jackson library to deserialize the data.
Instead, Spring relies on the Spring Beans library.

With Jackson, the fields deserialization needs only setters and if we also want to serialize the object we need to provide getters too.
With the Spring Beans library, things are different : it relies on the JavaBean model

The central Spring component to handle beans is the `org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapper` interface.

Its javadoc states :

> The central interface of Spring's low-level JavaBeans infrastructure.
>
> Typically not used directly but rather implicitly via a
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory or a
>   org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.
>
> Provides operations to analyze and manipulate standard JavaBeans: the
>   ability to get and set property values (individually or in bulk), get
>   property descriptors, and query the readability/writability of
>   properties.

So as `BeanWrapperImpl` (the `BeanWrapper` implementation)  deserializes/serializes beans, it expects to manipulate JavaBean (getter and setter for each field).

The [`3.4. Bean manipulation and the BeanWrapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-beans) documentation refers also the JavaBean requirement :

> The org.springframework.beans package adheres to the JavaBeans
>   standard provided by Oracle. A JavaBean is simply a class with a
>   default no-argument constructor, which follows a naming convention
>   where (by way of an example) a property named bingoMadness would have
>   a setter method setBingoMadness(..) and a getter method
>   getBingoMadness(). For more information about JavaBeans and the
>   specification, please refer to Oracle’s website ( javabeans).

About your actual issue, we can notice that `BeanWrapperImpl` manages to deserialize to no collection fields with only setters associated to :

```
private int id;
private String title;
private String description;
private int pages;
```

But it doesn't deserialize to a collection field that has only a setter declared  :

```
private List<Price> prices;
```

Finally, this issue is conforms to the spring bean specification : JavaBeans is required.
So you need to have both a setter and a getter for `prices`.
Spring is so only less demanding with no collection fields.